# Web api 2 security - key for api

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api2, xamarin.forms

I'm building an API that my public mobile app (xamarin forms) will call to get information. However to delimit the users of the API to just my app for security reasons, I want the public mobile app (xamarin forms) to pass a key to be able to call the API. Is basic authentication the best option then ? Or is there another approach ?

Comment: Just use the builtin OAuth stuff as you get with the SPA template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any Auth based mechanism in your web api project. The best would be the latest Identity 2.0 using Owin.

> OAuth is an open standard for authentication, and enables a resource
>   owner to notify a resource provider that permission should be granted
>   to a third party in order to access their information without sharing
>   the resource owners identity.

In your Xamarin client project (mobile app) use the Xamarin.Auth SDK to authenticate your users. It provides many features and also helps you to scale and use Social authentication as well.

> [Xamarin.Auth](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth) is a cross-platform API for authenticating users and
>   storing their accounts. It includes OAuth authenticators that provide
>   support for consuming identity providers such as Google, Microsoft,
>   Facebook, and Twitter.

The authentication flow when consuming an OAuth identity provider is as follows:

1. The application redirects a browser to an identity provider URL. The
   URL query parameters indicate the type of access being requested.
2. The identity provider handles user authentication, and returns an
   authorization code to the application.
3. The application exchanges the authorization code, client ID, and
   client secret for an access token from the identity provider.
4. The application uses the access token to access APIs on the identity
   provider, such as requesting basic user data.

The application uses the OAuth2Authenticator and OAuth2Request classes, provided by Xamarin.Auth, to implement the application side of the authentication flow.

The detailed explanation of [Authenticating Users with an Identity Provider
Using the Xamarin.Auth component for authentication implementing](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/oauth/) is available [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/oauth/).